# An alternative class for Tracert with DNS feature

Tags: c#

I noticed, using Tracert on Windows, that if there is no data for DNS info, there is a delay too long to be acceptable - more or less 5 seconds. For this reason, I coded my own Tracert class with a latency parameter, waiting for an answer. All is done using a Task method. However, if I code for a few years, now I am trying to elaborate my code cleanly and efficiently. Please, can you tell me what I should change? Maybe you see some mistakes or non-senses. Thank you for your help ++
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhjdX.png)

```
class TraceRoute
{
    public void TraceRouteX(string ipAddressOrHostName, int hops = 30, int latency = 1000, bool dns = false)
    {   // this way we can check if IP or HostName are valid 
        try
        {   // a tip to get only IPv4
            IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(ipAddressOrHostName).First(address => address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

            using (Ping pingSender = new Ping())
            {
                PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();
                Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[32]; // 32 bits as packet
                string hostName; // for DNS
                PingReply pingReply;

                pingOptions.DontFragment = true;
                pingOptions.Ttl = 1;
                int maxHops = hops;
                // just a first message on screen before TraceRoute
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(" TraceRoute to {0} with a maximum of {1} hops, setting latency to {2} and DNS feature to {3}\n", ipAddress, maxHops, latency, dns));
                Console.ResetColor();

                for (int i = 1; i < maxHops + 1; i++)
                {   // for latence
                    stopWatch.Reset();
                    stopWatch.Start(); // ping options allows us to set TTL                  
                    pingReply = pingSender.Send(ipAddress, latency, new byte[32], pingOptions);
                    stopWatch.Stop();

                    if (dns)
                    {   // DNS resolving using a timer
                        Task<string> task = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            var t = Dns.GetHostEntry(pingReply.Address).HostName;
                            return t.ToString(); // well well ?
                        });
                        // waiting an answer
                        bool success = task.Wait(latency);

                        if (success)
                            hostName = task.Result;
                        else
                            hostName = "TimeOut (no DNS info)";                  
                    }
                    else
                        hostName = "";
                    // display string with all informations - easy reading
                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
                    else
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    // display final output
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(" h{0}\t{1} ms\t{2}\t\t{3}", i, stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, pingReply.Address, hostName));
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    // status
                    if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n The IP target " + pingReply.Address + " has been reached");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                        break;
                    }
                    // increment TTL to get the next node
                    pingOptions.Ttl++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(" ERROR: You Have Some TIMEOUT Issue Or An Invalid IP/Host");
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to get this migrated to [codereview.se] if it's working code and you just want improvement ideas

Comment: Thank you Charlieface. I didn't know this possibility. I will do ++

Comment: Don't just copy this over. Preferably raise a moderator flag (by clicking the Flag button) and get a mod to do it