# Artificially create a connection timeout error in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, api, timeout

I want to call an external Api in my application and after calling the Api if a timeout exception throws then my app returns a result. Now I want to **simulate** this situation.
this is my code :

```
 public string Sample()
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response =
                    client.GetAsync("ExternalApi").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                //...
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return ((HttpRequestException) e).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout ? "timeOut" : "Error";
        }

        return "Success";
    }
```

If I throw a TimeoutException in **ExternalApi** then in **Sample** method I get Internal server error.
**How to create an artificial timeout exception?**

Comment: Please show relevant code

Comment: `How can I create a real timeout exception?` Have the server take a very long time.

Comment: You can check this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100841/artificially-create-a-connection-timeout-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, I finally use an application called 'Hercules Setup Utility'. This application listens to a **port** in 'Tcp Server' and get your request but doesn't respond at all. After executing this app and listening to a port, you have to set something like localhost:**port** in your app. You will get a timeout exception.

Answer (score 2):

The HttpClient class has a [Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-5.0) attribute.

So try this.

```
using (HttpClient client 
     = new HttpClient(){Timeout=new TimeSpan(0,5,0)})
```

for a five minute timeout.

If the timeout expires you'll get a WebException.

Comment: I suspect if you want a timeout it may be better to set it to a _very short_ value.

Answer (score 1):

The HttpClient class has a Timeout attribute. Or you can use some apps to create timeout like Hercules Setup Utility

Answer (score -1):

I recently did an alternative to Tracert using a Task method so as to get an exception if something goes wrong sending a request for DNS info. I guess that you should use Task<>. Take a look at the main MSDN explanation :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-5.0

Also I think that you could appreciate how I check success or exception in my own code. Take a look at the code inside the boolean DNS check :

[An alternative class for Tracert with DNS feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693815/an-alternative-class-for-tracert-with-dns-feature)